# Unable to store mysql result inside external variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous

I tried every thing I can find online to make this work but none of them worked. I making query to sql database and then trying to store the result on a variable in a global scope. I tried it by returning a promise, using call back using await but none of them worked.
 Please I need help.

```
const checkEmailUsed = (email) => {


let sql = "SELECT * FROM users_signup WHERE user_email = ? LIMIT 1";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conn.query(sql, email, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(res[0]);
    });
    conn.end();
  });
};

var user = [];
checkEmailUsed("mikias@email.com")
  .then((res) => user.push(res))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

console.log(user); // Still []
```

Answer (score 0):

It thinks it's true, it's because your console run first than the query.

This is an example:

Imagine you use an example a cloud mysql database. Then your connection need 10s to get the result.

It's mean, when your query waiting for the result, you console has been execute.

So, to solve that problem, maybe you can try this code below with simple `async/await`:

```js
const simpleFunction = async () => {
  const users = await checkEmailUsed("mikias@email.com");
  console.log(users);
}

simpleFunction();
```

Yeah, that's an example from your case.

Comment: I tried your example here, but it didn't solve my issue. I still can use it outside the simpleFunction. the users contains a value inside of it, if there is user then i want to set a boolean outside the function to true, else to false. But I can to that, or even store the value of users on a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how javascript works. Your example will always log an empty array. Your query function is an asynchron operation which will always resolve on a later event loop, this is also true for every promise. `console.log` will always be executed before the `users.push` if you are setting it up this way.

We can look at this example, where we create a promise which is immediately resolved.

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2));
console.log(1);
```

It will always log 1, 2. How can you try to think about this?

At first you have to know that javascript will always compute all "synchron" code until there is nothing else to do. We might just call this the "callstack" wich is all the code of your program which will get worked of sequentially. A promise on the other side is asynchron and code which should be run when the promise is resolved will be placed in the "callback queue". Javascript looks if there is code in the callback queue if it has nothing on the callstack.

In this example we basically have two operations on the callstack. `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2))` and `console.log(1)`

javascript will compute this like that.

"Is something on the callstack?" => yes => `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2))`

Take `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2))` form the stack and execute it.

This will immediately place `() => console.log(2)` on the callback queue.

"Is something on the callstack?" => yes => `console.log(1);`

This will log "1" to the conolse

"Is something on the callstack?" => no

"Is something on the callback queue?" => yes => `() => console.log(2)`

Put `() => console.log(2)` on the callstack

"Is something on the callstack?" => yes => `() => console.log(2)`

This will log "2" to the console.

Comment: I tried to understand your explanation , thank you very much I am trying to sink it in. But What should I do in my case. What is the solution, if i want to store the the data inside the promise in a global variable?

Comment: Your are already storing your data in the global variable. You are just logging the variable before the data has been set. The question is what do you want do achieve with this global variable?

Comment: ok so, checkEmailUsed function will make query to db, which returns a user if there is any user with that email address else it will be empty list. If there is a user I want to change a global boolean variable from false to true, if there is no user then the global variable will be false. I tried it but I couldn't change the value of the variable inside then()

Comment: You can definitely change the value of a global variable inside of then. But you can't check log the global variable by a synchron `console.log`. Does this example clear things up? https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-bush-c1tkk?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Sir, I tried to do it exactly like you showed me but it doesn't work still. I am also confused. in your code it works perfectly its not work on mine.